# jsoup clean html entities

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I need some help to clean user inputs with jsoup, I want to remove all known HTML tags but let `<` or `>` if there are not part of a real HTML tag.

`Jsoup.clean("<b>test</b> te<st <test >test", Whitelist.none())`

the current output is
`test tetest`

and I want:
`test te<st <test >test`

thanks for your help.

Comment: this doesn't look related to scala

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup doesn't provide that kind of functionality. Check the below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static String removeTags(List<String> tags, String source) { 

        if(tags == null || tags.size() == 0) return source;

        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String tag : tags) {
            strb.append(String.format("</?%s.*?>|", tag));
        }

        return source.replaceAll(strb.substring(0, strb.length() - 1), "");

        //strb example : "</?span.*?>|</?em.*?>"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String str = "<b>testj</b> te<st <test >test";
            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            tags.add("b");
            System.out.println(removeTags(tags, str));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```